# How do I get IP address with Zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I'm new to Zabbix so question might look like a real newbie one.

I have a task where VM has hardcoded IP address of external service and this address wants to be monitored. Once DNS have different IP address than on VM - it should make alert as VM problem.

For example, amazon.com IP address `205.251.242.103` hardcoded into VM. Once amazon.com has `205.251.242.104` that differs from hardcoded one - Zabbix should alert on that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Zabbix key `net.dns.record[<ip>,name,<type>,<timeout>,<count>,<protocol>]` to check how the host is resolving the name.

You can use a trigger to compare strings since Zabbix version 5.0, for example:

`{host1:vfs.file.contents[/etc/os-release].last()}<>{host2:vfs.file.contents[/etc/os-release].last()}`

Depending on how the value is hardcoded, you will use different keys to extract the value. For example use `vfs.file.contents[]` if the hardcoded value is inside a file (like the hosts file).

> don't hardcode values if you can avoid it...

See: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent#net.dnsipnametypetimeoutcountprotocol

Comment: Agreed on hardcoding but it's hardcoded not in my dev team so I can't do anything on it.

Thanks a lot with ```net.dns.record```. Will check it out. For now got an ```External check``` with shell script with ```dig``` command in it. And will redo my trigger on the one you provided maybe it will suit better.